# SQL with few JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, compiler-errors

I want to do few inner join but have wrong - what I do incorrectly?

```
    SELECT genre.title title1, country.title title2 FROM  movie
      -- genre
      INNER JOIN genre ON genre.id = genreRelation.id_genre
      INNER JOIN genreRelation ON movie.id = genreRelation.id_movie

      -- country
      INNER JOIN countryRelation ON movie.id = countryRelation.id_movie
      INNER JOIN country ON country.id = countryRelation.id_country
    WHERE movie.id = 1
```

Comment: Well, what is the error????

Comment: Please show the error message

Comment: @OldProgrammer, @Mikpa sorry but I doing this sql in PHPsthorm - it doesn't show error!  but I have the next: ` is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
 Software caused connection abort: socket write error
` and please read comments for the next answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mixing up tables in joins where they are not defined in the ON clause.

try this

```
 SELECT genre.title title1, country.title title2 FROM  movie
  INNER JOIN countryRelation ON movie.id = countryRelation.id_movie

  INNER JOIN genreRelation ON movie.id = genreRelation.id_movie
  INNER JOIN genre ON genre.id = genreRelation.id_genre

  LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = countryRelation.id_country
  WHERE movie.id = 1
 GROUP BY country.title
```

Comment: Order of joins is immaterial

Comment: @echo_me is right...JOINS with genreRelation and genre should be in correct order

Comment: @DipenduPaul yeah . the query reads first the first join and see what condition in on clause , so if the table is not defined yet the join will not work. Jim looks he dont know this.

Comment: @echo_Me but I have an error. And me need some natural join, as if in column  genre.title will be about 100 lines and in country.title about 10, then other 90 lines in last column will with "null" value!

Comment: @echo_Me but if I do, like the next code I have a duplicate!(in my example - duplicate in country), so code: `SELECT genre.title title1, country.title title2 FROM  movie
  INNER JOIN countryRelation ON movie.id = countryRelation.id_movie

  INNER JOIN genreRelation ON movie.id = genreRelation.id_movie
  INNER JOIN genre ON genre.id = genreRelation.id_genre

  INNER JOIN country ON country.id = countryRelation.id_country
WHERE movie.id = 1`

Comment: then you need a left join.

Comment: look my edited answer , and please show your error which you said you got error

Comment: @echo_Me, oh yes! I haven't any error. BUT it make duplicate in country! how I can doing for right or left path of result with "null" but do not doing some like now - with duplicate ?

Comment: to prevent duplicates then consider to use GROUP BY. look edited

Comment: @echo_Me sorry, I'm sorry, but this code does not work. but if I change the key Bind on title2 it will print only as many fields as in title2, conversely, if you change the error. Yes, I would like to see the fields in the left or right side as the number may be more or less in a given column.

Comment: @echo_Me oh, it work but show only one line, cause in country only one line, but in genre - two

Comment: Sir ! can you create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) example , and edit your question and put your wished result and i will be glad to help, because i dont really understand what you want.

Comment: @echo_Me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddecb see, please. I want to show all result from country, genre, actor, director, title for current movie!

Comment: you mean like that ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddecb/4

Comment: or this ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddecb/14

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddecb/18 see please!  I want don't take duplicate!!!

Comment: I need is the final version of that will show the actual values. But without repetition.

Comment: without repetion in what column ?

Comment: In any column (since the repetitions will be different)!

Comment: i dont know at all where is repetitions , you want this ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddecb/25

Comment: i have concatenated title2 to every title1 , this is what you need ?

Comment: @echo_Me, no. TITLE2 have values as "w" and "q". I want to have in result table two rows IN THIS COLUMN with this value, without repetitions! BUT other rows MUST have empty value as NULL

Comment: You mean you need only the first occurrence of a country and the "following" rows with NULLs? This is a reporting task, which should be done on the client.

Comment: you want this ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddecb/31

Comment: @echo_Me yes, but columns TITLE1 must be like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddecb/25

Comment: dude please edit your question and put there your wished result

Comment: @echo_Me http://postimg.org/image/5qgq1ftz3/ this is what I want! It is really?

Comment: As I wrote: This is a reporting task, do it in the client.

Comment: oh. I think it really to do in server. Thanks guys. I understand this!

Answer (score 0):

In the ON-clause you can only use columns form previously joined table, so reorder the join logically and add a DISTINCT to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT genre.title title1, country.title title2 FROM movie
  -- country
  INNER JOIN countryRelation ON movie.id = countryRelation.id_movie
  INNER JOIN country ON country.id = countryRelation.id_country
  -- genre
  INNER JOIN genreRelation ON movie.id = genreRelation.id_movie
  INNER JOIN genre ON genre.id = genreRelation.id_genre

WHERE movie.id = 1
```

Comment: The last packet successfully received from the server was 306 827 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 306 827 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

Comment: @serge: What's the meaning of this comment? Is your/my query running longer than 5 minutes and there's a timeout, or what?

Comment: no sorry. But you sql code is not right cause is this text, I don't know current error. Please, see this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284979/sql-with-few-join?answertab=oldest#comment33856386_22285010